# Django url passing unknown number of parameters

Tags: python, django, url

In Django, I am trying to pass unknown number of parameters to url in the template. To explain, I have urlpatterns in urls.py for example,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:arg1>/', views.foo1, name = 'url1'),
    path('<str:arg1>/<int:arg2>/', views.foo2, name = 'url2'),
]
```

In my views.py,

```
def url1(request):
    return render(request, 'template1.html', {'arg1': arg1})

def url2(request):
    return render(request, 'template2.html', {'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2})
```

And to bind to `href` attribute in `a` tag in the templates, the template should look like:

```
<!-- In template1.html -->
<a href = "{% url url1 arg1 %}">Link</a>

<!-- In template2.html -->
<a href = "{% url url2 arg1 arg2 %}">Link</a>
```

In this case, I want to merge `template1.html` and `template2.html` into `template.html` like following:

```
<a href = "{% url url_name url_args %}">Link</a>
```

And views.py:

```
def url1(request):
    args = {
        'url_name': url1,
        'url_args': (arg1, ),
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', args)

def url2(request):
    args = {
        'url_name': url2,
        'url_args': (arg1, arg2),
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', args)
```

How do I pass `url_args` to the template? I tried passing `url_args` in tuple, list, and dictionary. But it wouldn't match prorperly. How should I pass `url_args` and code in `template.html` to make `a` tag to bind the link properly?

Comment: You probably swapped `url` and `name`?

Comment: oh thanks for notifying me that